# Position sticky within a flex container

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, sticky

I'm trying to build an application using the following schema:

[image]

The left side of the page is doing ok; the red sticky part is fixed and the content beneath it is scrolling just fine.

Problem appears when i try to scroll the right part of the page.
I don't know how to manage to get both the `overflow-x/y` on the right (**gray**) container AND the brownish div to be "stickied".

Removing the `overflow-x: auto` on the gray div seems to do the trick but then the right content is not wrapped anymore into the page.

**EDIT:**

Added example.
I recommend opening it in full page and resize it in a smaller window, in order to get both  the scrolling (done it in a hurry, sorry)

```html
<!-- 
  
  CYAN div should be "stickied" to the main container while scrolling on y axis (as the orange one does)
  For the sake of example (to show overflow issues exc...) i've set the width to 50% (in final app should be 100%)
    
-->


<div style="display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; background-color: black; width: 50%; ">
 <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 16%; background-color: yellow; ">
  <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; position: sticky; 
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000; padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    height: 600px;
    font-size: 12px; background-color: orange">
   <div style="display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%;">
     A
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%;">
     A
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%;">
     A
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%;">
     A
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%;">
     A
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: red; height:40px; padding-top: 0px;">
      D
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: red; height:40px; padding-top: 0px;">
      D
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: red; height:40px; padding-top: 0px;">
      D
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: red; height:40px; padding-top: 0px;">
      D
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: red; height:40px; padding-top: 0px;">
      D
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: red; height:40px; padding-top: 0px;">
      D
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: red; height:40px; padding-top: 0px;">
      D
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: red; height:40px; padding-top: 0px;">
      D
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: red; height:40px; padding-top: 0px;">
      D
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: red; height:40px; padding-top: 0px;">
      D
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: red; height:40px; padding-top: 0px;">
      D
    </div>
    
 </div>


 <!-- removing overflow-x: auto seems to do the trick but then the right content is not wrapped anymore (look at the black div width) -->

 <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 80%; background-color: green; overflow-x:auto; align-self: flex-start;">
  <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000">
   <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    height: 600px !important; ">
    <!-- <div *ngFor="let item of columns" style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: cyan">{{item}}</div> -->
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: cyan">B</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: cyan">B</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: cyan">B</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: cyan">B</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: cyan">B</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: cyan">B</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%; align-self: flex-start;">
   <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap;">
     <!-- <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; height: 100%; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: brown" *ngFor="let item of columns">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; height:100%">
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%" *ngFor="let row of rows">
        {{row}}
       </div>
      </div>
     </div> -->
     <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; height: 100%; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: brown">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; height:100%">
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
               <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; height: 100%; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: brown">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; height:100%">
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
               <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; height: 100%; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: brown">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; height:100%">
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
               <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; height: 100%; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: brown">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; height:100%">
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
               <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; height: 100%; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: brown">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; height:100%">
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
               <div style="flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0; height: 100%; min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px; background-color: brown">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; height:100%">
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
       <div style="height: 40px; flex: 0 0 auto; width: 100%">
        C
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using so that your problem can be replicated and inspected properly? Here is a link to information about how to present a problem effectively [mcve]

Comment: There's a stackblitz link at the end of my question ( https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ke9qyl). I preferred that since i'm using a flex grid package for my app (primeflex: https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeflex), so i had to provide an example with that npm package installed.

Comment: Code posted @Danny ;)